# How to stack and hide images in a Div in order to animate between them (without floats)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am currently making a grid layout for my site.  What I want is a set of 9 images to load as fast as possible, and then, after the page loads, I want to retrieve more images, add them to the image containers and animate between them.  I know how to do the transitions, but I do not know the best way to stack the images in order to animate between them.  Create `img` nodes and appending them as children just adds them to the page. Additionally, trying to absolutely position each element wreaks havoc on my layout.

I know floating them would prevent the images from taking up vertical space but, as I am not using floats right now, I want to avoid using them just to stack images.

If you look at my HTML I am basically just trying to create a stack of several images in the `divs`, all of them on top of each other.

Any guidance would be great.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test1.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test2.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test3.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test4.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test5.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test6.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test7.png"></div>
    <div class="imageHolder"><img class="homeImages" src="test8.png"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this javascript to preload the new images after page loads:

```
    var imageHolders = document.querySelectorAll('.imageHolder');
    var imageArray = [
        'media/refined/newImage.png',
        'media/refined/newImage1.png',
        'media/refined/newImage2.png',
        'media/refined/newImage3.png',
        'media/refined/newImage4.png',
    ];
    var imageNodeArray = [];
    for(var i = imageArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
           imageNodeArray.push(this);
        };
        img.src = imageArray[i];
    }
    document.onclick = function() {
        imageNodeArray[0].setAttribute('class', 'changed opaque');
        imageHolders[0].appendChild(imageNodeArray[0])
    }
```

And the CSS is really what is getting me:

```
#mainContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2.2em 0;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.imageHolder {
    display: inline;
}

img {
    width: 30%;
}

.changed.opaque {
    opacity: .5;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set position of your main container as `relative` and of each image containers as `absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ehu5j/

Comment: This makes all of the image containers (divs) stack on top of each other also (which I do not want).  I only want to stack the dynamically added `imgs`

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to stack if not the images. When you say "and animate between them", what type of animation are you exactly referring to? How should the newly loaded images look on the existing layout? On the top of the current images? below the existing images but stacked?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Here is a **rough** example.  http://alijafarian.com/demos/responsive-image-grids-using-css/ I want the homepage to have a 3 x 3 grid, initially loaded.  Then I want to use CSS3 Transitions to transition to new images.  I do need the original placement and layout to remain the same, just the images changing.

Comment: I think he wants the images in the holders to stack. Which is simply putting `relative` on the holders and `absolute` on the images.

Comment: @Knyri +1 on your solution

Comment: Yes, this is almost perfect however, for some reason this makes my initial layout different.  Now all three rows of images stack to just one row.  I really only want additional images to stack.  My idea was that by appending child images to each node, I can have a stack of images to transition between.